How to untabify on a project level when Org publishing
I know how to untabify on a file
(untabify (point-min)
              (point-max))

But I can't seem to figure out how to untabify on a small function I  created for org publishing to .md files. To put it into context, I'm exporting a bunch of .org files into .md files and removing formatting conversion issues, such as indentation and interpreting _ (underscore)
(let ((org-publish-project-alist
       '(("my-org-notes"
         :base-directory "~/Desktop/what/"
         :publishing-function org-md-publish-to-md
         :publishing-directory "~/Desktop/what2/"
         :base_extension "org"
         :with-sub-superscript nil
         :section-numbers nil
         :base-extension "org"
         :with-toc nil))))
  (org-publish-all))


Can you add the "small function" that does the clean-up to your question please?
